# nginx configuration file throws error while gridfs configure?

Tags: mongodb, nginx, gridfs

I have installed nginx-gridfs and followed https://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs.

Nginx installed successfully.

In nginx.conf file I have specified as below:

```
server{
  location /gridfs/ {
  gridfs my_app;
  }
}
```

It throws an error gridfs is unknown directive.

```
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "gridfs" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:69
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Any one suggest solution.

Thanks,
Prasad.

Answer (score 0):

While compiling nginx from its source code and then installing it using make install it gets installed in /usr/local/nginx instead of the /etc/nginx so the path and daemon created needs to be changed in the nginx scipt(which you have to create manually and link it since compiling from source code won't create its own).

I assume you've already installed nginx from its source code adding the gridfs module.

Now unfortunately, you can't start or stop the service of nginx using the script in /etc/init.d/nginx because installing from the source code won't create a script(if found in /etc/init.d/, then this script is previously generated while installing nginx using package manager)

Then check your nginx status. If it's running then use:

```html
sudo kill `cat /usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid`
```

then go ahead and create a script:

```html
sudo nano /etc/init.d/nginx
```

Inside the bank file use this code snippet:

```html
#! /bin/sh
 
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          nginx
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the nginx web server
# Description:       starts nginx using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO
 
#PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/nginx/sbin
#DAEMON=/usr/sbin/nginx
DAEMON=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
NAME=nginx
DESC=nginx
 
test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
 
# Include nginx defaults if available
if [ -f /etc/default/nginx ] ; then
    . /etc/default/nginx
fi
 
set -e
 
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
 
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /usr/local/nginx/logs/$NAME.pid \
        --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS || true
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile /usr/local/nginx/logs/$NAME.pid \
        --exec $DAEMON || true
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile \
        /usr/local/nginx/logs/$NAME.pid --exec $DAEMON || true
    sleep 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \
        /usr/local/nginx/logs/$NAME.pid --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS || true
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  reload)
      echo -n "Reloading $DESC configuration: "
      start-stop-daemon --stop --signal HUP --quiet --pidfile /usr/local/nginx/logs/$NAME.pid \
          --exec $DAEMON || true
      echo "$NAME."
      ;;
  status)
      status_of_proc -p /usr/local/nginx/logs/$NAME.pid "$DAEMON" nginx && exit 0 || exit $?
      ;;
  *)
    N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
    echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
 
exit 0
```

Then make the file executable:

```html
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx
```

Now add the script to the default run levels:

```html
sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f nginx defaults
```

That's it. You are done! You can now use the script to start, stop and restart nginx:

```html
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start

sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop

sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Follow this link if you need more help: [1](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/ubuntu-and-debian-installing-nginx-from-source)

At the bottom of the page you'll find the link to create the nginx script manually.